# Hibernate @OrderColumn creating two queries instead of one

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an application that has a parent entity and multiple lists of child entities. These lists are ordered so we want to use the Hibernate @OrderColumn feature.
We unfortunately have issues with this, hibernate is issuing more SQL requests than expected

I replicated it in a simple example, data model is:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @OrderColumn(name = "pos")
  private List<Child> childs;

  public Parent() {
  }

  public Parent(List<Child> childs) {
    this.childs = childs;
  }
}

@Entity
public class Child {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private int pos;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  private Parent parent;

}
```

My test is really simple:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(new Parent(Arrays.asList(new Child(), new Child())));
tx.commit();

sessionFactory.close();
```

In Hibernate logs we can see:

```
Hibernate: insert into Parent (id) values (default)
Hibernate: insert into Child (id, parent_id, pos) values (default, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Child (id, parent_id, pos) values (default, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update Child set pos=? where id=?
Hibernate: update Child set pos=? where id=?
```

Why this `@OrderColumn` is creating update queries, when adding/modifying a child we can see in the logs 2 queries: one for the insert/update with pos = 0, and then a second one to update the position with the right value.

Getting the position is something very straightforward, why it cannot be done in the insert/update query?

If needed I can provide a sample application replicating this

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is sorting, I think @OrderBy might be what you are looking for ... @OrderColumn forces hibernate to keep the pos column up to date to reflect the proper order on the flushing of the transaction ... simple sorting can be done with @OrderBy

Comment: I could do the sorting with @OrderBy but then I have to maintain the pos manually before saving into db, hibernate needs to keep the pos column up to date but why it's not happening before the insert query, it's just an indexOf on the list

Comment: I do not think it could ... as records could have been added or removed from the db in other hibernate sessions etc ... it would only know for sure what the pos needs to be once the transaction is open and it looks at whats in the database, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The way the @OrderColumn annotation functions is the cause of your problem with Hibernate doing more SQL calls than necessary.

When you add or update a Child entity, Hibernate first performs the insert/update query with the pos column set to 0. This is because Hibernate doesn't know the final position of the Child entity in the list until after it has been added or updated.

After the insert/update query is performed, Hibernate then updates the pos column of the Child entity to its correct position in the list using a separate update query. This behavior is expected and is the way that Hibernate handles the ordering of entities with the @OrderColumn annotation. Unfortunately, I think that there is no way to eliminate these extra update queries with @OrderColumn.

As [James Gawron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75149591/11649863) said, one way to avoid this problem would be to use a @OrderBy annotation instead of @OrderColumn. The @OrderBy annotation allows you to specify the order of the child entities based on an attribute of the child entity, rather than a separate column in the child table. This eliminates the need for Hibernate to update the order column separately, as the order is determined by the attribute specified in the @OrderBy annotation.

Another option would be to manually manage the position of the child entities using List interface methods like add, remove, and move. This way, you will have full control of the order of the child entities. Like this:

```java
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child1 = new Child();
Child child2 = new Child();
parent.getChilds().add(child1);
parent.getChilds().add(child2);
```